# Trouble with list padding function types

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm working on a function that pads a list of Num with 0s until it is at least as long as the requested length.

```
main = do
       putStrLn $ show ( padList [1,2,3] 5)

padList :: (Num a) => [a] -> a -> [a]                  
padList x len = if length(x) >= len then x else padList ((x ++ 0) len)
```

But I keep getting:

```
prog.hs:9:49:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a]'
                with actual type `Integer -> [Integer]'
    In the return type of a call of `padList'
    Probable cause: `padList' is applied to too few arguments
    In the expression: padList (([0] : x) len)
    In the expression:
      if length (x) >= len then x else padList ((x ++ 0) len)
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong?

I'm trying to append x to list [0] until I get:

```
[1,2,3,0,0]
```

However, my lists might be float so:
[1.0,2.0,3.0] might become => [1.0,2.0,3.0,0.0,0.0]

I'm not too concerned with performance, I'm just trying to learn functional programming.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to fix it:

```
padList :: (Num a) => [a] -> Int -> [a]
                             ^^^
padList x len = if length(x) >= len then x else padList ([0] ++ x) len
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The expression `([0]:x)` means that x is a list and `[0]` is an example of an element of x. That is, x is a list of a list of Ints.

The expression `[0] ++ x` means that both `[0]` and `x` are lists of the same type, i.e. both are lists of Ints. Alternatively you could use `(0:x)`.

Also, `length x` returns an Int, not a general `Num a`, so you can't use `a` as the type for the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things are wrong here, so let's break it down:

```
padList :: (Num a) => [a] -> a -> [a]                  
padList x len = if length(x) >= len then x else padList ((x ++ 0) len)
```

The type of length is `length :: [a] -> Int`, so when comparing `length x >= len` this forces `len` to be of the type `Int`. Since a more specific type is required then what you've declared this will throw an error. This can be fixed by changing the type signature.

```
padList :: (Num a) => [a] -> Int -> [a]
```

The type is now correct, but the function still isn't. The type of `(++)` is `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` which means it expects all the elements to be of the same type.

If you were to define the function

```
padList x len = if length(x) >= len then x else padList (x ++ 0) len
```

without a type signature the compiler would actually except it due to the `Num` typeclass. But the inferred type would be `Num [a] => [a] -> Int -> [a]`

This is because what you're actually doing when doing `(x++0)` I have a `x` which is of some type `[a]` and a `0` which is of type `Num a => a` so if I should be able to use `(++)` on these two items, then there must be a Num instance out there for `Num [a] => a`. This is most certainly not what you want.

Instead you want to add the list of `[0]` to `x` :

```
padList x len = if length(x) >= len then x else padList ((x ++ [0]) len)
```

Now to answer your original problem, the error you're getting

```
`padList' is applied to too few arguments
```

is because you're extra parenthesis are making the compiler think that `((x ++ [0]) len)` is one argument, it's thinking you're applying `(x ++ [0])` to `len`. You don't want the parenthesis

```
padList x len = if length(x) >= len then x else padList (x ++ [0]) len
```

also the one around `length(x)` isn't needed either, you can simply do `length x`